# User management customization in openfire

Tags: xmpp, chat, openfire

I am new to Openfire. I have installed it with external database till now. I am working on a full fledged chat app where most of the default Openfire features. I have no experience nor knowledge no how to develop Openfire plugin. Following is one of the feature that I need to customize according to my requirement-

User details registered by default is Username, Password, Email and so on.
However in my chat client I need to take Profile Image, Cover Image, Phone number and so on.

Please help me with codes or links where I can get help.

Thankyou

Comment: I am studying openfire and now I got that for customizing openfire we need to write openfire plugin. May anybody please help with codes on plugin I need to develop for Extending User Details in openfire database

Comment: Are Profile Image and Cover Image Strings?

Comment: Ok thats bad, otherwise you could use already available user properties where you could save key/value pairs (Strings), without to change/add any code.

Comment: Oh is it? Ok then it's great idea, I can keep urls to user profile and cover image

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in 2 ways :

1. You can create web services in openfire. You can customize userservice plugin and add the services you need.

Here is the link of user service plugin.
http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/userservice/readme.html

You can find the code in openfire code which is opensource.
https://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/source.jsp

2. You can create web service in some other language may be php. Just use openfire for chat server and do web services in php. This way will also reduce connection pool issue if you want openfire to scale in future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, User Service is RestApi plugin now. I have installed this plugin. But registration is process done by openfire with auto created open fire user's db. I am basically trying to add new columns to this auto generated db if this approach is correct. I couldn't find such customization facility in RestApi plugin. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You have to customize it yourself check the java code. You can add more columns or add another table with foreign key username